# SlickGrid requires a valid container, #myGrid does not exist in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slickgrid

I've been trying to use SlickGrid Dataview with Json but to no avail. I keep getting the above error. "JavaScript runtime error: SlickGrid requires a valid container, #myGrid does not exist in the DOM."

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
```

And this is the script file to load `json`:

```
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

 //sample data
 var columns = [{
     id: "CodeID",
     name: "CodeID",
     field: "CodeID",
     width: 50
 },
 {
     id: "Name",
     name: "Name",
     field: "Name",
     width: 200
 },
 width: 100
 }
 ];
 var options = {
     enableColumnReorder: false,
     multiColumnSort: true
 };
 // wire up model events to drive the grid
 dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
     grid.updateRowCount();
     grid.render();
 });

 dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
     grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
     grid.render();
 });


 $.getJSON(my_url, function(data) {
     dataView.beginUpdate();
     dataView.setItems(data);
     dataView.endUpdate();

 });
```

---

If I don't use dataview and iterate throught json data and pass it to the grid everything works fine but when I use dataview I get the error above even though I have a div with Id="myGrid".

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, I was using SlickGrid.js and grid.js files. So it ran container two times. So removing grid.js solved the problem. Also make sure that document is ready before running new Slick.Grid()

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are loading your JS at the top of the page and before "myGrid" exists.

In that case, try to use `$( document ).ready()` like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

//sample data
var columns = [
    { id: "CodeID", name: "CodeID", field: "CodeID", width: 50 },
    { id: "Name", name: "Name", field: "Name", width: 200 },
    width: 100 }
];
var options = {
    enableColumnReorder: false,
    multiColumnSort: true
};
// wire up model events to drive the grid
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    grid.render();
});


$.getJSON(my_url, function (data) {
        dataView.beginUpdate();
        dataView.setItems(data);
        dataView.endUpdate();
});
});
```

JS executed within the `$( document).ready()` callback won't be initialized until the entire document loads.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Pachonk, but I have this error now: Unhandled exception at line 204, column 23 in http://localhost:4000/Scripts/slick.grid.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I put var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

after the columns initialization but now I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at line 106, column 11 in http://localhost:4000/Scripts/slick.dataview.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Each data element must implement a unique 'id' property.

any idea?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: Or paste your exact code and how you incorporate the JS in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

I solved the problem by putting the grid and dataview in the $.getJSON function as follows and all is fine for now.

```js
$.getJSON(my_url, function (items) {


//get data from Json  looping through Json items

.....


var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
// wire up model events to drive the grid
dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});

dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    grid.render();
});

dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();
});
});
```